# General Commutative Law for Propositional Logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am working with the book called *An Introduction to Mathematical Logic* by Richard E. Hodel.  Thus far, he has derived Rules of Inference from the rules the Formal System P given below:

Rules of Inference:

(1) $A \lor (B \lor C)$ $\therefore$ $(A \lor B) \lor C$

(2)  $A$ $\therefore$ $(B \lor A)$

(3) Contraction (Cnt): $A \lor A$ $\therefore$ $A$

(4)  $A \lor B, \neg A \lor C$ $\therefore$ $B \lor C$

Propositional Axiom Schema:

(1) $A \lor \neg A$

I have derived all other argument forms, Modus Ponens, Modus Tollens, Hypothetical Syllogisms, etc. I have understood and written most of my own proofs as guided by this book.

Hodel also goes on to derive extended/generalized formulas as expressed below:

(1) $A \lor (B \lor (C \lor D))$ $\therefore$ $((A \lor B) \lor C) \lor D$

(2) $A \lor B$ $\therefore$ $A \lor (C \lor B)$

(3) $A \lor (B \lor B)$ $\therefore$ $A \lor B$

(4) $A \lor (B \lor C), A \lor (\neg B \lor D)$ $\therefore$ $B \lor C$

I am here to ask the question which is posed in the exercises of section 3.3 which asks the reader to derive the commutative rule $A \lor (B \lor C) \therefore A \lor (C \lor B)$ from these rules of inference together with the Axiom Scheme (1). I know the answer must be obvious and I have written it down before about 5 years ago. I just keep forgetting the necessary niche required to derive this rule.

Comment: It is obvious if Axiom schema is swapped...

Comment: Yes, @MauroALLEGRANZA , but to swap you need to derive $A\vee\lnot A~\therefore~\lnot A\vee A$  which basically is the commutation we need to prove.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA please revise your comment about the axiom schema. I have made the appropriate adjustment to my question which was initially posed incorrectly

Comment: @GrahamKemp Please revise your comment about the commutation of the axiom schema, since changes have been brought to light. Regards

Comment: Pay special attention to the last paragraph, specifically the rule $A \lor (B \lor C) \therefore A \lor (C \lor B)$

Comment: IMO rule (4) is wrong; it must be: $A∨B,C∨¬A  ∴ B∨C$ because it must "embed" commutativity.

Comment: Alternatively, see [Shoenfield, ML (1967)](https://www2.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~krajicek/shoenfield.pdf) page 21, where the four rules are the same above but the **Axiom** is: $\lnot A \lor A$.

Comment: Thank you for your avid response @MauroALLEGRANZA. I have looked at the details of the book you have showed me. To be honest, the lemma 2 on page 28 seems more similar to what we are discussing in this question. I do however think I have come up with a best solution which I will post as the answer soon after refining the argument a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Let us first derive the commutative rule (Cm; the following labels of the inference rules are Hodel's, see addendum):

$A\vee B\tag{Hyp}$
$\neg A\vee A\tag{Axiom}$
$B\vee A\tag{Cut}$

Then:

$A\vee(B\vee C)\tag{Hyp}$
$(A\vee B)\vee C\tag{Assoc}$
$((A\vee B)\vee C)\vee B\tag{Exp}$
$(A\vee B)\vee (C\vee B)\tag{Assoc}$
$(C\vee B)\vee (A\vee B)\tag{Cm}$
$((C\vee B)\vee A)\vee B\tag{Assoc}$
$B\vee((C\vee B)\vee A)\tag{*Cm}$
$\neg B\vee B\tag{Axiom}$
$A\vee(\neg B\vee B)\tag{Exp}$
$(A\vee\neg B)\vee B\tag{Assoc}$
$B\vee(A\vee\neg B)\tag{Cm}$
$C\vee((B\vee(A\vee\neg B))\tag{Exp}$
$(C\vee B)\vee(A\vee\neg B)\tag{Assoc}$
$((C\vee B)\vee A)\vee\neg B\tag{Assoc}$
$\neg B\vee((C\vee B)\vee A)\tag{*Cm}$
$((C\vee B)\vee A)\vee((C\vee B)\vee A)\tag{Cut with *-lines}$
$(C\vee B)\vee A\tag{Cnt}$
$A\vee (C\vee B)\tag{Cm}$

**Addendum**

[image]